# Why do all elements disappear with "*" selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D59o2.png)

I'm learning JQuery through w3school. And I came across this example.
From my understanding, `$("*").dblclick()` bind the double click event to each element in the document (each element has its own event and they are seperated).

And, I expect that, after double clicking a `<p>` element, only the one clicked will disappear. However, when I click a `<p>` element, every `<p>` element disappears. May I know how is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Please post your code as text in the question itself, never as image. And for your issue, your understanding is right, **every** element will have this event added to it. The bit you are missing is that `<html>` and `<body>` also are elements and they also have this event added to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `*` in `$("*").dblclick()` is a **selector** as explained in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

To which `*` means "all the elements", referencing the DOM structure of HTML, `<body>` is also an element, and JQuery is indeed appending the event on it as well, so when you say *"when I click a `<p>` element"*, what you should actually mean is _"when I click the `<body>` element".

That is because the `<body>` element is hierarchically positioned higher than the `p` elements, and the event is being triggered on that element because it takes precedence over the `p` which `body` contains.

So, your code is working absolutely fine. But if you wanted, for example, that *"after double clicking a `<p>` element, only the one clicked will disappear"*,
maybe your code should look something like this:

`$("p").dblclick()`

Which means, *find all `p` elements and bind this event* and will comply with your expectations.

Hope you let me know what happened when you tried it out! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`"*"` selects ALL elements, including `<body>` and `<html>` (https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/). So, if you double click one of your paragraphs, the event will be triggered three times, one for `<p>`, one for `<body>` and one for `<html>` generating this "undesired" behavior. If one of your `<p>` was inside, lets say, a `<div>`, the event would be triggered four times. One way to prevent this is to stop the event propagation.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "*" ).dblclick( function( event ){
        console.log( event.target.innerHTML );
        console.log( event.target.parentElement.tagName );
        $(this).hide();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>bbbbbb</p>
<p>cccccc</p>
<div>
    <p>dddddd</p>
</div>
```